# How to remove Multiple elements from an Array by name

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove multiple elements from an array by name

This is my code

```
var mularr = ["jQuery","JavaScript","HTML","Ajax","Css"];
var itemstoRemove = ["jQuery","HTML"];
for(var i=0;i<itemstoRemove.length;i++)
{
   mularr.splice($.inArray(itemstoRemove, mularr),1);
}
alert(mularr);
```

Could anybody please let me know how to remove multiple elements from a array by name ??

Answer (score 3):

You just need to iterate the `itemsToRemove` -

```js
var mularr = ["jQuery","JavaScript","HTML","Ajax","Css"];
var itemstoRemove = ["jQuery","HTML"];
for(var i=0;i<itemstoRemove.length;i++)
{
   mularr.splice($.inArray(itemstoRemove[i], mularr),1); // note the [i]
}
console.log(mularr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you. Just click the checkmark next to the answer @user3674364

Answer (score 1):

```
var main = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,9];   // main array                                                              
var removedItemsIndex = [0,2,4];  // array of index to delete of main array
var result=[];
for(var i=0;i<main.length;i++){
    if(removedItemsIndex.indexOf(i)==-1)
    result.push(main[i])
}
console.log(result)
```